# using custom class defined within storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uikit

In Xcode I can define a custom class within the identifier inspector but how can I use them? Following example:

[image]

```
class c1 : UITableViewCell {

  func celltest() {
        let i = 99;
    }
}

class NicePlaceTableViewController: UITableViewController {
.
.
.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath)
        **cell.celltest()** .. has no member celltest
        let place = places[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = place.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(place.timestamp)"
        return cell
    }
```

If the reuseIdentifier will be known but not its custom class - in this case "c1" - how can I access the methods defined within the class c1 without violate Xcodes compile checks?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to force convert it to `c1`:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as! c1
cell.celltest()
```

Btw, `c1` is not a good class name.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to typecast the cell as the object of `c1`. You can do that by writing below code in `cellForRowAt` method like this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as! c1
```

Thus the compiler would know the type of your custom tableview cell class and `cell.celltest()` won't give you an error.

Another reference to swift style guide which can help you greatly with class names and method names :

https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the class name "c1". Is there any way to get it dynamically? I don't catch why the cell is queried by its reuseIdentifier "cell1" and xcode doesn't know about the class which the cell should be specified? (c1)

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't work like that. You have to type cast the cell(with the class assigned in the storyboard) then only you can use the custom tableview cell's properties and methods.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode Interface Builder is a IDE to visualy create a UI sceans.

Your configuration of a cell which is inside a tableview will instantiate a NicePlaceTableViewController with a c1 cell registered in the tableview.

If there is no Xcode with Interface Builder tool you have to had create it programmaticaly by yourself as follows:

```
class NicePlaceTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(c1.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell1")
    }
}
```

This code registers a class type for a given identifier. To access a cell you have to use a tableView.dequeueReusableCell method which will act on an internal pool to create or reuse a cell.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath)
}
```

A dequeued cell is a UITableViewCell type. If you would like to downcast it to c1 type then you have to use ! operator.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1", for: indexPath) as! c1
```